# Mapping a field name beginning with an underscore in Entity Framework 4.1 Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have a class that contains a few private/protected fields and some public getters that return the value of the fields.  I am attempting to map the fields to database columns using the fluent API on the DbModelBinder in OnModelCreating.  I cannot use an automatic property with a protected setter so please don't offer that as a solution to my question.  It would probably work I'm sure but I cannot use the automatic property as the domain class is shared code and used with other different ORMs that have different ways of mapping their fields and unfortunately one doesn't support the au

I use the following code (found on stackoverflow) to access the protected field so that I can use the expression when mapping:

```
public static class ObjectAccessor<T>
where T : class
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> CreateExpression<TResult>(string propertyOrFieldName)
    {
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "propertyOrFieldContainer");
        Expression body = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyOrFieldName);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<T, TResult>), body, param);

        return (Expression<Func<T, TResult>>)lambda;
    }
}
```

This all works wonderfully if the field name is m_username but if I use _username I get a ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: System.Data.Edm.EdmProperty: Name: The specified name is not allowed: '_username'.

I can't use camelcase without the underscore either as the helper above can't distinguish between the public Username property and the protected username field.  I'd really like to still keep using the underscore camelcase without the letter prefix.

Is it possible to configure the ModelBinder in some way so that the validation accepts the property name with a leading underscore?

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Comment: I get the sneaking suspicion that you are planning to shoot yourself in the foot. There are ways to load data into your domain object without breaking encapsulation/information hiding.

Comment: @Mark, I am sorry to ask this question, but what would motivate you to simultaneously use multiple ORMs in the same application? I get the impression you are in some sort of corporate environment, perhaps highly politicized, with multiple developers/teams. Most likely you are supporting some sort of behemoth internal application that probably already suffers from severe architectural fragmentation. Perhaps you cannot do it now, but I highly recommend that at some point, someone should standardize on only one ORM. Coding your app now is possible. Supporting it after will be a nightmare.

Comment: A valid point and certainly an architecture that I would not advocate - multiple ORMs in the same environment is not my intent.  However, the code in question is part of an abstract layer above the ORM that supplies an interface to common ORM behaviour, a framework for pluggable ORM providers if you will.  For example, I use an abstract way of defining fetching strategies that hides from the developer the ORM specific way of implementing eager loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that decoration of your field like this :

```
[Column("username")]
public string _username
```

maybe helpful in your case, anyway - please review [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203897/mvc3-naming-a-column-beginning-with-a-number)