# MVC3 naming a column beginning with a number

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am new to MVC3 C#. I need to have a column in the database called `3DSecureStatus` for legacy purposes.

When I call the column this and insert in the application I get this error:

> [ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected
>   during model generation:
>
> System.Data.Edm.EdmProperty: Name: The specified name is not allowed:
>   '_3DSecureStatus'. ]

In the application I am defining it as `public string _3DSecureStatus { get; set; }` because it doesn't like `3` being the first character of the column name.

Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: show your exact failing code please

Comment: The whole application doest work, thats the error i get when i run it

Comment: @Beginner, can you debug your application and step through it and show us the line where it fails? Or at least provide a stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.aspx) attribute to specify the database column name

```
[Column("3DSecureStatus")]
public string ThreeDSecureStatus { get; set; }
```

Or use fluent mapping like

```
Property(x => x.ThreeDSecureStatus).HasColumnName("3DSecureStatus");
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename `_3DSecureStatus` to something else.

Entity Framework Code First does not allow properties/columns to have underscores or numbers in the beginning of the name.

So you have to change this until this is fixed.

Comment: in the table i need it to be 3DSecureStatus

Comment: When i receive a post from sage it calls it 3DSecureStatus

Comment: Name it something else, I am trying to find a solution meanwhile. But it is interesting to see if it works. You don't need to have the Exact same naming as the calls from Sage have.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an Entity Framework error rather then an MVC error. It looks like from a bit of googling that underscores as the start of Code First field names are invalid and don't work. If you can, try putting a letter in front of it.