# Using numbers at the beginning of variable name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I'm mapping up data from an SQL database into an object in c#. The problem is, one of the columns is unfortunately named "100_hrs". So when I am making my C# object, I get an error in the declaration:

```
public float 100_hrs {get; set;}
```

I've tried using `@` in front but it does not work. If the property is not named the same as the table column, then it does not map up. How can I map this up?

Comment: How do you use this variable?

Comment: @gdoron it's mapped up to the table in the database. So the variable contains whatever data is in that table.

Comment: why not change your column name instead to match up your variable? instead of the other way around. In every programming language that I know that naming convention would result into compiler error.

Comment: @Thirdy I am not allowed to change the database because I am not the database manager.

Comment: Or.. use your ORM properly and map it however you want.. ?

Comment: What sort of ORM are you using to do that mapping?

Comment: which object-relational mapper are you using?

Comment: I'm using entity framework 5.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering why the `@` didn't work.

`@` lets you declare variables with keywords names, it doesn't allow you to use invalid tokens.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx)

Regarding to the main question, it seems like you should change the table column name.
If you're using some sort of mapping engine like NHibernate of EntityFramework, you can change the mapping file. Example:

```
[Column("100_hrs")]
public float hrs100 {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use column attribute as below

```
[Column("100_hrs")]
public float hundred _hrs {get; set;}
```

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.aspx)
- [MVC3 naming a column beginning with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203897/mvc3-naming-a-column-beginning-with-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use underscore before the number say _100_hrs since you could easily manipulate it by string extraction if you want to map it to your column? Although there is a little overhead it sure solve your problem.

Comment: In Visual Studio, constructor auto generation will not work properly with underscore number variables.