# Entity Framework is auto-naming column incorrectly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using C# / Entity Framework (EF). I'm using the database first approach to generate the tables and stored procedures.

When I generate the stored procedure, my parameter name `p30CharacterDescription` is named incorrectly by EF. It should be `30CharacterDescription` without the (`p`) in the front.

My database table has the column name written like this: `30CharacterDescription`. I'm not sure why EF is adding that extra p to the parameter name.

Why is EF adding that extra p to the front of the parameter and how can I solve this issue? Can I tell EF to name the parameter without the p in front?

[image: mo]

Comment: You can see this question/answers for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008007/using-numbers-at-the-beginning-of-variable-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property names must start with either a letter or underscore, so the prefix is a necessity.

It won't affect how your code functions, as it will still be mapped to the correct database column.